# Jquery : Selectors and Hidden

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, children

I have some input and i want to fill them with a value i got from a text.
Here's my code :

```
$( "#dialog-test fieldset" ).hide();
$( "#dialog-test fieldset:eq("+j+")" ).show();
$(this).children(".testValue").each(function(k,item) {
    $( "#dialog-test fielset:visible input").eq(k).val($(this).text());
});
$( "#dialog-test" ).dialog( "open" );
```

This dosn't work cause #dialog-test is hidden and so :visible dont return anything.
This works , but i could to open my dialog only when im done changing all values:

```
$( "#dialog-test fieldset" ).hide();
$( "#dialog-test fieldset:eq("+j+")" ).show();
$( ".ui-dialog:eq(2) .ui-button-text:first" ).text("Modifier le test");
$( "#dialog-test" ).dialog( "open" );
$(this).children(".testValue").each(function(k,item) {
    $( "#dialog-test fieldset:visible input").eq(k).val($(this).text());
});
```

I would use the first solution but cant manage to find how process so that this :visible works.

Thank a lot for your help,
Tim

Comment: Similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mfHDg/) ?

Comment: That helped me, i edited my question cause my problem is other in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
var $inputs = $( 'fieldset', '#dialog-test' ).hide().eq( j ).show().find( 'input' );

$( this ).children( '.testValue' ).each(function ( i, val ) {
    $inputs.eq( i ).val( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: does using the square bracket notation return a dom element and not a jQuery object?

Comment: That's perfect, thx a lot ! Just another question. I have inputs and select, how can i adapt your solution to add selects in the find().

Answer (score 0):

You may try the eq filter to select by index the coresponding input:

```
$(this).children(".testValue").each(function(k,item) {
    alert($(this).text());
    $( "#dialog-test input:visible").eq(k).val($(this).text());
});
```

Regards

Etienne

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var visible_inputs = $('#dialog-test input:visible');
var i =0;
$(this).children('.testValue').each(function(){
    $((visible_inputs)[i++]).val($(this).text());
});
```